# Cisco 1841: Can someone decipher this feature/package code?

Tags: cisco, router

Looking at a used Cisco 1841 router with the following feature/package "code"; I'm assuming there's a T1 interface and 128MB of Flash RAM, but the rest I'm not sure of:

```
W/WIC-1DSU-T1-V2 IP BASE 32FL 128DR
```

Really want to know how many Ethernet interfaces and what speed, IPSec capable/how many, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IP Base` is the IP Base IOS image.  This dictates which features you will have available to you (and IPSec isn't in IP Base).

`32FL` is 32MB of Flash... this is how much space you have to store IOS images.  As long as IOS supports the size of CompactFlash, you can use just about any CF card... just format it with IOS.

[The Cisco 1841 Datasheet](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps5853/product_data_sheet0900aecd8016a59b.html) contains most of the other answers you are looking for (the 1841 as two 10/100 ethernet ports).

If you're looking for IPSec, you need a `k9` image (either `Advanced Security` or `Advanced IP Services`).  See the [IOS Packaging Bulletin](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/iosswrel/ps8802/ps5460/prod_bulletin0900aecd80281b17.html) for the big picture of how Cisco organizes features into images.

Answer (score 2):

[This document from Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps221/product_data_sheet09186a00801a9184.html) should have everything you need:

> FEATURES
>   • T1 or fractional T1 network
>   interface
>
> • Wet T1 support (not available on
>   WIC-1DSU-T1)
>
> • N x 64 kbps or N x 56 kbps
>   nonchannelized data rates (N = 1 to
>   24)
>
> • Standards-based, including ANSI
>   T1.403 and AT&T Publication 62411

Answer (score 1):

- WIC-1DSU-T1-V2 --> has T1 WIC module with integrated DSU (version 2)
- IP BASE --> IOS image type; note does not specify IOS ver (as mentioned, no encryption; IP-only, does not support IPv6) - if you have a CCO acct, you may d/l another IOS type, but it must fit in Flash
- 32FL --> 32MB Flash (IOS files stored in Flash; this is kind of a small amt)
- 128DR --> 128MB DRAM (memory; IOS runs in DRAM, + routing tables, etc.)